# Using map access nested json in React Js

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to ready location property/object from fetched data of API. I successfully able to read single values but if I try same for nested it gives error Undefined.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ea5094d5e087f2afc01ebe1"),
"Title" : "Developer",
"Summary" : "DeveloperDeveloperDeveloper",
"JobDetails" : {
    "JobType" : [ 
        "fullTime"
    ],
    "StartDate" : ISODate("2020-05-01T04:05:54.000Z"),
    "EndDate" : ISODate("2020-05-14T14:00:00.000Z"),
    "Salary" : {
        "From" : 65000,
        "To" : 75000
    },
    "Location" : {
        "Country" : "Australia",
        "City" : "Sydney"
    }
}
}


let showJobs = jobs.map(
        j => (
            <div className='row'>
                //I tried j.jobDetails.location.country

                            {j.jobDetails.map(s =>
                                <span>
                                    {s.location.country}
                                </span>)
                            }
            </div>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object properties do not match the actual shape of the JSON. Most of the props are title-cased. So something like the folowing:

```
{j.JobDetails.map(s =>
  <span>
    {s.Location.Country}
  </span>)
}
```

You can troubleshoot issues like this in the future by using `console.log` or debugger breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

`jobDetails` not an array but an object. So you can access it's properties directly, because every property has a unique name. Also have a look on case sensitivity.

```js
<div className='row'>
  <span>
    {j.JobDetails.Location.Country}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, it gives me error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Location' of undefined

Comment: In my controller i am returning json like this             x.Id, x.Title, x.Summary, x.JobDetails.Location, x.ExpiryDate, x.Status

Comment: @RahulWaghmare can you do `console.log(jobs)` before the `jobs.map` and update your question? It seems like your posted input data is not what the real data looks like.

Comment: data is same I checked

Comment: @ Auskennfuchs Fetched jobs[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Can you output  `Title` or `Summary` of one job?

Answer (score 0):

Your data type is Object, you can maping data type array in this code, and your data in array is string type.

`data.JobDetails.JobType.map((el, idx) => 
    <span key={idx}>{ el }</span>
)`

if you want to access data location you can this.

`<span>{ data.JobDetails.Location.Country }</span>`

`<span>{ data.JobDetails.Location.City }</span>`

Comment: What error message? you can using console.log outside return component. data is sample name because i don't know variables your data.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that results returned from API will be array of objects, you can iterate over that array and then for each object you can access `JobDetails` directly and you don't have to `map` over it as `JobDetails` is an object and not an array.

So you can do

```
jobs.map((job, index) => {
    console.log(job.JobDetails.Location.Country); // this will print country name
})
```

Working jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/aztu8of3/